# `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error with S3 upload PresignedURL created in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, postman

`SignatureDoesNotMatch` error occurs when uploading a file using the PresignedURL created with the following source code.
File uploads are done via Postman.

Please tell me how to troubleshoot.

```
def call(env)
    Aws.config.update({
        region: '*region*',
        credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('*accessKeyId*', '*secretAccessKey*')
    })
    key = "test/image.jpg"
    bucket_name = '*bucket_name*'
    signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(signature_version: 'v4')

    if key
        body = signer.presigned_url(:put_object, bucket: bucket_name, key: key)
    else
        body = ""
    end

    body
end
```

- I have checked if the accessKeyId, region, secretAccessKey and bucket_name are correct.

Response Header Example(some are masked):

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: *request-id*
x-amz-id-2: sSbb********************************************************************98=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2022 01:49:12 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

Response Body Xml Example(some are masked):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>*Here is accessKeyId*</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20221121T014413Z
20221121/ap-northeast-1/s3/aws4_request
d1ffe599b69868e*********************************************25a3</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>4f51*********************************************db31f6******f735</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 ...*Byte array follows here*</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/test/Receipt3.jpg
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=*Here is accessKeyId*%2F20221121%2Fap-northeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20221121T014413Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&amp;x-amz-acl=public-read
content-type:image/jpeg
host:*bucket name*.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 ...*Byte array follows here*</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>*request-id*</RequestId><HostId>sSbbjrOYs9d4aAf************GSIvc************CSJhGPR************98=</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your code using the call method? And can you post the actual response headers with the error?

Comment: Add Response Exmple.Thank you.